# Python: Fork support is only compatible with the epoll1 and poll polling strategies

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing

I am using one of the google cloud virtual machines to do my job and I am using multiprocessing library especially pooling and pandarallel. Sometimes I am getting this error:

"Fork support is only compatible with the epoll1 and poll polling strategies".

Does anybody encountered this error?
Thank you.